# How to redirect url to the url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I didn't know how to question this but my problem is like this

I have written a rule for a url

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?store=$1
RewriteRule ^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products index.php?store=$1&view=products
RewriteRule ^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+) index.php?store=$1&view=products&category=$2
RewriteRule ^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/single/([0-9]+) index.php?store=$1&view=single&product=$2
```

I am new to `htaccess` so I don't know much about it. Is there a way that even if a old url comes like `index.php?store=abc&view=single&product=123`
this will be redirected to a new one like `mysite.com.pk/abc/single/123`

Comment: Your first rule matches all rules currently, no? You should use closing anchor.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying chris!

Comment: 1. You need to change the order of those rules, otherwise it is _always_ the first rule that will be applied. 2. you want to use flags to end the rewriting process once a rule matches and 3. you want to add rules for an external redirection to achieve what you actually ask.

Comment: Without a closing anchor `^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will also match `^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products` requests because `^mysite.com.pk/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` allows anything after the match.

Comment: @chris85 I suspect very much that `mysite.com.pk` is meant to match the _host name ("domain")_ which will never happen in a `RewriteRule`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some small modifications to your proposed rules to get them to work. And you have to add additional rewriting rules to achieve what you actually ask: redirecting "old" URLs to your new syntax.

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products$ index.php?store=$1&view=products [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=products&category=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/single/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=single&product=$2 [END]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=single&product=123
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=single&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/single/%3 [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=products&product=123
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/products/%3 [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=products
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/products [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1 [END,R=301]
```

Those rules *should* work the same in a `.htaccess` style file *and* in the real http host configuration. Please see the note below about that.

If you are using an old version of the apache http server then you may have to replace the `END` flag by the `L` flag. Try that if you receive an "internal server error" (http status 500) and the server complains about the `END` flag in the error log file. You may have to add some additional conditions to prevent an endless rewriting loop in that case.

Please note that I did not test that rule set. I hope it does not contain any silly mistakes and you certainly will have to test it.

All of the above assumes that `mysite.com.pk` is meant to match your *host name ("domain")*. But that will not work, since the `RewriteRules` work on the request *path*, not the full URL. If you want to limit the application of the rules to a specific host, then you can add a leading condition to stop the rewriting process:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com\.pk`
RewriteRule .* - [END]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and will test it. And let you know and you note I have copied to my register... will give a study

Comment: Your rules are working. But I commented the rules and now when ever I type `index.php?store=abc` it keeps on redirecting to `abc/store=abc` even though I have deleted the `.htaccess` file

Comment: That sounds like you are loading from a cache. Clear and/or disable your browsers cache, make a "deep reload" and make sure you do _not_ use a proxy server.

Comment: You are welcome! And remember: please give back to this community yourself ;-)

Comment: @arkascha. I am surprised that `RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/products/%3 [END,R=301]` works. **1)** without `?` in the end, it's by default `[QSA]` and not `[QSD]`. and **2)** with `%3` normally stated in the manual _%1 to %9 provide access to the grouped parts of the pattern, from the **last matched RewriteCond**._ Is there been change in the operation with the latest versions?